# How to update props from completely separated component in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a web builder app which allows the user to customize the components.

How it works is to click the necessary component and then click the appeared component to show the configuration sidebar and configure it.

The problem is I'm stuck at the situation where I want to update the props from the component configuration sidebar which is dynamically rendered as well as the target component.

Could somebody please help me to find out a solution for this problem?

Please take a look at my code below:

`LayoutRenderer.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="layout-renderer">
    <GridLayout
      :layout.sync="components"
      :col-num="12"
      :row-height="30"
      :is-draggable="true"
      :is-resizable="true"
      :is-mirrored="false"
      :vertical-compact="true"
      :margin="[10, 10]"
      :use-css-transforms="false"
      :responsive="true"
      :auto-size="true"
    >
      <GridItem
        v-for="component in components"
        :key="component.i"
        :x="component.x"
        :y="component.y"
        :w="component.w"
        :h="component.h"
        :i="component.i"
      >
        <ComponentRenderer :component="component" />
      </GridItem>
    </GridLayout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from "vuex";
  import VueGridLayout from "vue-grid-layout";

  export default {
    components: {
      GridLayout: VueGridLayout.GridLayout,
      GridItem: VueGridLayout.GridItem
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        components: state => state.components.components
      })
    },
    created() {
      this.fetchComponents();
    },
    methods: {
      /**
       * Fetch component from the backend based on the pageId
       * occured by the vue-router's route parameters.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      fetchComponents() {
        let pageId = this.$route.params.component.pageId;
        this.$store.dispatch("components/fetchComponents", pageId);
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .layout-renderer {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 501px) {
    .vue-grid-item {
      height: fit-content !important;
      transform: none !important;
      position: relative !important;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }

  @media (hover: none), (hover: on-demand) {
    .vue-grid-item {
      height: fit-content !important;
      transform: none !important;
      position: relative !important;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

`ComponentRenderer.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="component-renderer">
    <!--
      Parent component

      This is where i want the props to be updated
      as well as the child component below.
    -->
    <Component
      :is="matches('Base', component)"
      :id="component.id.toString()"
      :name="slugged(component.title, component.type)"
      :label="component.title"
      :text="component.title"
      :content="component.title"
      :placeholder="component.placeholder"
      :value="component.options"
      :items="component.options"
      :required="component.required"
      name-obj="textOption"
      val-obj="valueOption"
      @click.native.prevent="select(component)"
    >
      <!-- Card header if any -->
      <template #header v-if="component.title">
        <h3 class="font-weight-bold" v-text="component.title"></h3>
      </template>

      <!-- Child component -->
      <Component
        v-for="(child, index) in component.components"
        :key="index"
        :is="matches('Base', child)"
        :id="child.id.toString()"
        :name="slugged(child.title, child.type)"
        :label="child.title"
        :text="child.title"
        :content="child.title"
        :placeholder="child.placeholder"
        :value="child.options"
        :items="child.options"
        :required="child.required"
        name-obj="textOption"
        val-obj="valueOption"
        @click.native.stop="select(child)"
      />
    </Component>

    <!--
      Component Configuration Sidebar

      This is where i should update the value of the props.
    -->
    <Component
      :is="matches('ConfigureBase', selected)"
      v-if="selected"
      :id="selected.id.toString()"
      :name="slugged(selected.title, selected.type)"
      :label="selected.title"
      :text="selected.title"
      :content="selected.title"
      :placeholder="selected.placeholder"
      :value="selected.options"
      :items="selected.options"
      :required="selected.required"
      name-obj="textOption"
      val-obj="valueOption"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      component: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        resizeSensor: null,
        clientHeight: null,
        selected: null
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.autoResizeParent();
      this.listenConfigPanelEvent();
    },
    methods: {
      /**
       * Set selected data when user click at a component.
       *
       * @param {Object} component
       * @return void
       */
      select(component) {
        this.selected = component;
      },

      /**
       * Convert component type string to match global-registered
       * base component name.
       *
       * @param {String} base ['NonSeparatedWords']
       * @param {Object} component
       * @return {String} BaseComponent
       */
      matches(base, component) {
        return base + _.capitalize(component.type);
      },

      /**
       * Handle size of the parent component as the child is being
       * added more and more.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      autoResizeParent() {
        const vm = this;
        this.gridItem = this.$parent;

        this.resizeSensor = new ResizeSensor(this.$el, () => {
          const widgetHeight = this.$el.clientHeight;

          if (widgetHeight !== vm.widgetHeight) {
            const h = Math.ceil(
              (widgetHeight + vm.gridItem.margin[1]) /
                (vm.gridItem.rowHeight + vm.gridItem.margin[1])
            );

            const newH = h;

            vm.widgetHeight = widgetHeight;

            vm.gridItem.eventBus.$emit(
              "resizeEvent",
              "resizeend",
              vm.gridItem.i,
              vm.gridItem.x,
              vm.gridItem.y,
              newH,
              vm.gridItem.w
            );
          }
        });

        this.clientHeight = this.$el.clientHeight;
      },

      /**
       * Slugify strings.
       *
       * @param {String} str
       * @return {String} ['something-separated-with-whitespaces']
       */
      slugify(str) {
        str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").toLowerCase(); // trim & force lowercase

        str = str
          .replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, "") // remove invalid chars
          .replace(/\s+/g, "-") // collapse whitespace and replace by -
          .replace(/-+/g, "-"); // collapse dashes

        return str;
      },

      /**
       * Combine title and type as a slugged name.
       *
       * @param {String} title
       * @param {String} type
       * @return {String} ['title-type']
       */
      slugged(title, type) {
        return this.slugify(title) + "-" + this.slugify(type);
      },

      /**
       * Listen to config panel events.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      listenConfigPanelEvent() {
        EventBus.$on("hide-sidebar", () => {
          this.selected = null;
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

**Edit: this is how the application looks like**

[image: the application preview image]

Comment: IMO solution is declare whole data in parent component and share it to children components (I would share a whole obj instead so many props). Then share a callback to each child component and call it from child to update everything you want.

Comment: The `ComponentRenderer.vue` is a children already, the parent is a `LayoutRenderer.vue` so I think I already did what is on your opinion. You can see the props on it declared with a name `component`. Should I put the code of the `LayoutRenderer.vue` too? How do you think?

Comment: Exactly, write the whole code to control your data in `LayoutRenderer.vue` and share callbacks to the children... if you do that, all your children will be updated and communicated between them. You need to think always like a one way flux: `Parent --> Children`. That's the key to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint anyway, but I still cannot imagine how to do it. I updated my question, please take a look.